# Get the list of tables from fabric workspace using abfss path

Tags: python, pyspark, spark-notebook, microsoft-fabric, data-lakehouse

I am currently attempting to retrieve the list of tables from a lakehouse located in a separate workspace by utilizing the ABFS (Azure Blob File System) path. Despite my efforts, the codes I have employed thus far have not yielded the desired outcome. I am now contemplating whether this task is feasible at all. Code Example shown below.

```
olspath = "abfss://path................"




#df=spark.read.format('delta').load(olspath)
#df=spark.read.load(olspath)
df=spark.read.schema(olspath)
#df.write.mode("overwrite").format('delta').save("Tables/"+"Account")
df.show()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `dbutils` you can get tables path, by checking them if it is delta or not you get tables.

```
dbutils.fs.ls("<Your_abfss_path>")
```

[image]

code:

```
from delta.tables import *
files = dbutils.fs.ls("Your_abfss_path")
print(f"Tables in given path")
for i in files:
    if DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark,i[0]):
        DeltaTable.forPath(spark,i[0]).toDF().show()
```

[image]

In Onelake

[image]

Comment: dbutils is not available outside of databricks environment. Getting error:
NameError: name 'dbutils' is not defined

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/onelake/onelake-access-python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/onelake/onelake-access-python)
Refer this doc.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Just as I finished this long post, I found another way to do it with a simple oneliner:

```
# no need for imports
mssparkutils.fs.ls("abfss://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy/Tables/")
```

---

Original post:

I was able to achieve it in Fabric by using the `fsspec` module, which is an unified Python interface for interacting with different types of file systems. It seems to be what `pyspark` is also using under the hood.

Initiate the filesystem:

```
import fsspec                       # Python unified interface for different file systems

# Inputs
filesystem_code = "abfss"           # Azure Blob File System Secure
onelake_account_name = "onelake"    # This is "onelake" for everyone
onelake_host = "onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com"

# Initiate filesystem
onelake_filesystem_class = fsspec.get_filesystem_class(filesystem_code)

onelake_filesystem = onelake_filesystem_class(
    account_name=onelake_account_name,
    account_host=onelake_host)
```

This gives a `fsspec_wrapper.trident.core.OnelakeFileSystem` object, which seems to be only available within Fabric. I got an error trying to get a "abfss" filesystem class on my local device.

List files (tables) with the filesystem object:

```
import os

# Inputs
workspace_id = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
lakehouse_id = "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
directory = os.path.join("Tables")     # add additional nesting as needed

# Get file list
dir_path = os.path.join(workspace_id, lakehouse_id, directory)
dir_contents = onelake_filesystem.ls(dir_path, detail=True)

for item in dir_contents:
    print(item)
```

Sample result:

```
{'name': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/Tables/mytable1', 'size': None, 'type': 'directory'}
{'name': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/Tables/othertable', 'size': None, 'type': 'directory'}
{'name': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/Tables/anothertable', 'size': None, 'type': 'directory'}
```

You can get the `workspace_id` and `lakehouse_id` from the abfss path of any table in the lakehouse that you're trying to list. The abfss path has the following format and you can find it in object properties:

`abfss://xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@onelake.dfs.fabric.microsoft.com/yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy/Tables/table_name`

[image]

I'm not quite sure if some specific permissions are needed - I just have access to both workspaces in Fabric and it seems to work.

Comment: Hi Mart, doesn't this throw when the path doesn't exist?

Comment: I guess you could wrap it with mssparkutils.fs.exists(f) condition.

Comment: @sqlconsumer.net, you are absolutely correct. Non-existent paths is something I did not consider in the original post. Unfortunately `mssparkutils.fs.exists(f)` also assumes that the path is a legit lakehouse abfs path or a local path starting with Files/ or Tables/.

I can't think of a throw-proof way without some weird catching logic. Somehow, it seems to be a common theme with current Fabric that even the most basic operations have several layers of complexity piled on top. :)